# How to check recaptcha in confirm_login_allowed?

Tags: django, authentication, recaptcha

I'm novice in the Django framework and I'm trying to add some extra defence to my log in page.

I'm using built in Django's auth system and want to add the recaptcha validation.

Is that possible to add reCAPTCHA validation in the **confirm_login_allowed** method?

In my forms.py:

```
class MyAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
    recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response') # Here is the stuck!
    url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
    values = {
        'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
        'response': recaptcha_response
    }
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode()
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=data)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    result = json.loads(response.read().decode())

    if not result['success']:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Captcha Validation Failed.', code='invalid_captcha')
```

And sure I have an error in this line:

```
recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
```

Is there a way to get request in this method or is threre a better way?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Bringing reCAPTCHA inside the `conform_login_allowed(self, user):` is not a good idea. Restricting the user at the **very beginning of the view** which is mapped to the URL responsible for login functionality is a better way to do it. Something like:

```
#All the dependencies. 
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
import requests

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response' , None)
        data = {
            'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
            'response': recaptcha_response
        }

        r = requests.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', data=data)
        result = r.json()
        if result['success']:
            pass
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Error! reCAPTCHA verification failed.")
        #Now you are done with the reCAPTCHA verification. Now bound the AuthenticationForm as described below.
        credentials = dict()
        credentials['username'] = request.POST['username']
        credentials['password'] = request.POST['password']

        form = AuthenticationForm(data=credentials)
        #... Rest of your logic ...
        #from here you can do any further validation inside your confirm_login_allowed(self, user) method in the forms. 
        #Or simply log-in the user to the django server in the form's confirm_login_allowed(self, user).
        #Basically whatever you were doing before. 
        #Except the reCAPTCHA validation part.

    else:
        #...  request.method == 'GET'  ... 
        #Code to accept GET requests only. LOGIN FORM gets displayed from this block. 

    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

The information was slightly incomplete in the question, so I answered it with the best of my knowledge. If this is not what you want, tell me and I'll try another approach. 
PS: Putting the reCAPTCHA validation inside a decorator can be in accord with the DRY principle. Look for that too; if this works.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm try to avoid function based view because of using the built in Django's auth system based on the class-based views such as LogInView class. In the latest Django release login() and logout() functions are deprecated.
And i find the solution to get the recaptcha response. 
Instead of 
recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
I'm using 
recaptcha_response = self.data['g-recaptcha-response']